# How can I prevent my computer from accessing thousands of websites?

Tags: dns, internet, blocking, hosts-file, opendns

I'd like to block access to domains from my computer.

This is what I tried

1. I tried to use the domain filter in my router, but it applies only the HTTP websites. Any website that relies on HTTPS gets by the filter, even if the filter is looking for a domain with the same name, and that makes this approach not work.
2. I put the list of websites in my `/etc/hosts` file. It's thousands of websites and my `/etc/hosts` file was at 200MB. I had to delete this because my internet speed slowed down to a standstill. My internet wouldn't work at all.

I'm reading about LittleSnitch (which seems hard to configure with thousands of sites) and OpenDNS. I found OpenDNS unsatisfactory because I can't upload my list of domains, and their list is missing many of the websites that I have as part of my list.

I don't want to set up a white list because I may want to access other sites.

Comment: Create outbound firewall rules to block connections to the websites.

Comment: I can't edit the firewall due to the organizational settings with my macbook